Did Kant claim that there is a difference in perception between space and other phenomenal properties?
Bertrand Russell when talking about philosophical questions raised by Kant said,

Let us now try to consider the questions raised by Kant as regards space in a more general way. If we adopt the view, which is taken for granted in physics, that our percepts have external causes which are (in some sense) material, we are led to the conclusion that all the actual qualities in percepts are different from those in their unperceived causes, but that there is a certain structural similarity between the system of percepts and the system of their causes…..


But there is no difference in this respect between space and other
aspects of perception, such as colours and sounds. All alike, in their
subjective forms, are known empirically; all alike, in their objective
forms, are inferred by means of a maxim as to causation. There is no
reason whatever for regarding our knowledge of space as in any way
different from our knowledge of colour and sound and smell. (Pages
716-717 of A History Of Western Philosophy)

Does Kant claim that our perceptual knowledge of space (and I’m presuming time) is fundamentally different from other kinds of perceptions?

For Kant the intuition of space and time is not presumed to be identical, on the contrary, they're critically different as time is applied to the inner sense to produce images while space is applied to the outer sense which is not actually in Kantian ontology, and this is partly why constructive arithmetic a la Heyting was strongly inspired by Kantian intuition of time, and geometry especially non Euclidean geometry has little to do with Kantian space intuition, if not outright conflict with it…

Russell's analogy is an outlier. Kant went with the consensus, confirmed by modern psychology, that space is not directly perceived at all, unlike sounds and colors, it is an inferred abstraction. We perceive the contents, not the container, the "fundamental difference" is not Kant's idea. His original contribution was to propose that space neither reflects something objective (as in Newton) nor is a theoretical construct to organize relational data (as in Leibniz), but is rather a footprint left by our faculty of sensibility in its framing of perception, a "form of intuition", as he put it.

@Conifold re your "nor is a theoretical construct to organize relational data (as in Leibniz)", it could be said that there's little difference between Leibnizian theoretical relational construct and Kantian space as "a form of intuition" scheme since Kantian intuition is also a theoretical construct albeit intuitively relating to "our faculty of sensibility" as some footprint left by sense impression. Therefore on this score Kant didn't surpass Leibniz at all...

@DoubleKnot Kantian intuition is not a theoretical construct. Constructs organize data after the fact, Kant's forms of intuition actively shape it, something Leibniz would not accept, and operate subconsciously. Neither theory "surpasses" the other, they are just different.

OP: "Does Kant claim that our perceptual knowledge of space (and I’m presuming time) is fundamentally different from other kinds of perceptions?"
Yes, he says they are different, as stated in The Critique of Pure Reason:

Sensible intuition is either pure intuition (space and time) or
empirical intuition of that which, through sensation, is immediately
represented as real in space and time. B 147

Also as commented in note 13 on page 32 of Heidegger's Kantbuch, in which he goes on to explain on pages 48-51

§ 9. The Elucidation of Space and Time as Pure Intuitions


What is represented in pure intuition is not an essent (no object,
i.e., not something that appears) but yet not absolutely nothing. It
is all the more necessary, then, to disclose both what is represented
in, and only in, pure intuition, and how the mode of representation
corresponding to it is to be delimited.
According to Kant, the pure intuitions are space and time.


In his disclosure of the essence of space and time, Kant, in each
case, deals first with the negative characteristics of the phenomenon
and only then with the positive characteristics from which the
negative follow.


Spatial relations — the relations of beside, above, and in back
of — are not localized "here" or "there." Space is not just another
thing on hand; it is no empirical representation, that is, nothing
that can be represented empirically.


Space must be represented as that "within which" any actual thing can
be encountered. Space is a pure representation, i.e., that which is
necessarily represented in advance in finite human cognition.


Pure intuition as intuition, however, must not only give that which is
intuited immediately; it must give it as a whole. This act of pure
intuition is no mere reception of a part; in such an act the whole is
present with the part. "Space is represented as an infinite given
magnitude." B
39
To say that space is a magnitude does not mean that it is of such and
such an extent [Grosses], nor does the expression "infinite
magnitude" mean of "limitless extent." Rather, "magnitude" here means
"extensiveness" [Grossheit] as that which makes being of such and
such an extent (quantity) possible. "The quantum wherein alone all
quantity can be determined is, with regard to the number of parts,
indeterminate and continuous; such are space and time." 40

Kant's Posthumous Works


